# Backbone Validation scope problems

Tags: validation, backbone.js

I'm trying to localize a application here and I did it on my model validate messages with something like that:

```
var userModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
     validate_msgs: {
     empty_name: msg.empty,
     min_length_name: msg.min,
         max_length_name: msg.length,
         invalid_name: msg.invalid
},

     validation: {
            name: [{
                required: true,
                msg: function(){ return this.validate_msgs.empty_name; }
            },{
                minLength: 3,
                msg: function(){ return this.validate_msgs.min_length_name; }
            },{
                maxLength: 30,
                msg: function(){ return this.validate_msgs.max_length_name; }
            }, {
                fn: "validateName"
            }]
        },

});
```

But the "this" on the return function of the msg is always pointed to the view as in :

```
Backbone.Validation.bind( this,  {valid:this.hideError, invalid:this.showError});
```

How can I handle this? Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The simple and obvious solution would be to just use the validation messages directly:

```
msg: msg.empty
```

But I assume you have a reason for mapping the error messages in your `msg` object to more specific error messages on the model. You can achieve this by defining the validation messages as static properties on the model class, and reference the properties using the model class name directly:

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  validation: {
    name: [{
      required: true,
      msg: function() { return UserModel.validate_msgs.empty_name; }
    }]
  }
}, 
{
  validate_msgs: {
    empty_name: msg.empty,
    min_length_name: msg.min,
    max_length_name: msg.length,
    invalid_name: msg.invalid
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't have access to the "UserModel" object. "ChannelModel.validate_msgs is undefined"

Comment: @ThiagoMirandadeOliveira, looks like you've named your model with lowercase `u`, so it would be `userModel`. I guess I instinctively changed it, since it's the usual naming convention to use capital first letter for `new`able classes.

Comment: Actually it's not a naming problem. I don't have access to the model on the Backbone Validation invalid function ( I really don't know why, though ). 
But I have made a solution here. My code is something like this:
    showError: function(view, fieldName, msg) {
   var vmsg = msg.apply(view.model, []);
   view.$('div.alert-error.' +       fieldName).removeClass('hide').find('span.msg').text(vmsg);
  },